# Fetching groups/users from Azure application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm developing a system where user can give access for fetching users/groups from his/her azure account.
I did following:

- Create B2C tenant (Initially tried B2B)
- Create enterprise application
- Set "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" for "signInAudience"
- Provide group.readAll, user.readAll, offline_access etc permissions
- Then ask for adminconsent using
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=xxxx&state=state&redirect_uri=url
- After response in redirect_uri, I'm accessing "client_credentials" using client secret, which returns token.
- Using that token, I'm fetching groups & users for that account using graph API.

Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0

Everything is working fine for my account. But if I trying with other personal user (which I haven't added as guest user in my tenant), then it returns error.

```
User account is a personal Microsoft account.
Personal Microsoft accounts are not supported for this application unless explicitly invited to an organization
Try signing out and signing back in with an organizational account.
```

I have tried through another account, which is also in azure and has few users in his account.
So Azure don't allow to fetch users/groups from any account which has users in his azure account?

Help me to find out if I missed something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documents for both Users and groups for fetching the list of them is not supported for personal Microsoft accounts.
[image]

Hope this helps.